# How can i customize code formatting for javascript?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example i need spaces between parentheses and arguments:

```
var myPrivateMethod = function( name, value ) {
  for ( var i = 0, l = this.stack.lenght; i < l; i-- ) {
    this.stack[ i ][ name ] = value;
  }
};
```

vs default VS Code JS formatting

```
var myPrivateMethod = function (name, value) {
  for (var i = 0, l = this.stack.lenght; i < l; i--) {
    this.stack[i][name] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064480/how-do-you-change-the-formatting-options-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @IsmailM I think that question is not a match for what he is asking.

Comment: Code formatting existed in vs code, but question is how edit preferences to make own option for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this 'beautify' extension for visual studio code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

I am not sure it has the ability to add spaces between parentheses and arguments but it allows you customize code formatting.