# Formatter for VSCode which puts a space before a colon

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, formatting, formatter

At my new job the convention is to put a space before the colon like so:

```
{
    "a" : "1"
}
```

Is there any formatter, a setting, or similar which does this for VSCode? I tried prettier, but that just removed all the spaces. Language is javascript, if that matters

Edit: I know how to use a formatter, I just don't find one that will put a space before a colon. Maybe there's one that allows me to use regex for formatting?

Comment: set up use prettify in your project or check for vs studio formatter shortcut

Comment: I think Visual Studio does it. And does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064480/how-do-you-change-the-formatting-options-in-visual-studio-code) help you?

Comment: @brk What is prettify? Do you mean beautify? I know how to use a formatter I just don't find anything to put spaces before those colons

Comment: @skrrrt I'm not using VS though. Not really, but thanks. I know how to use a formatter I just can't find one that does what I need it to do. Maybe there's a way to put a regex or something inside a formatter to do that kinda stuff?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettify

Comment: @brk thanks! But sadly I couldn't find something in there or in that js-beautify :/

Comment: @matthesinator did you please find some solution? Which formatter for VScode allows space before colon?

Comment: @mikep Sadly not, had to do it manually all the time

Comment: @matthesinator ESLint has feature `key-spacing` that we are looking for: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/key-spacing Can you try it? ESLint is available for VScode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: @matthesinator it is working, I have posted official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using `ESLint` https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint + it's option `key-spacing` https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/key-spacing ...

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
    ...,
    "rules": {
        ...,
        "key-spacing": [
            "error",
            {
                "afterColon" : true,
                "beforeColon" : true,
                "mode": "strict"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Longer answer if you are not familiar with ESLint:

- in project root run `npm install eslint` (or probably could be installed globally)
- in project root run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init` or `npm init @eslint/config` to configure .eslintrc.json
- maybe restart of VSCode is needed

Note: .eslintrc.json can be used in root and also in subfolders to maintain different ESLint options (for e.g. `resources-frontend-browser` files and `resources-backend-nodejs` files)