# My python code is auto wrapping in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

When I write Python code in VS code, it takes too much control of how it looks, which to me makes it harder to follow. Is there a way i can stop it auto wrapping lines?

What I want:

```py
tn.write(('print(sci:StateString())' + '\n').encode('ascii'))
state = (tn.read_until(b">  ").strip(b">  ").decode('ascii'))
state = state.rstrip()
```

What I'm getting:

```py
tn.write(
    ('print(sci:StateString())' + '\n').encode('ascii'))
state = (tn.read_until(b">  ").strip(
    b">  ").decode('ascii'))
state = state.rstrip()
```

Comment: What code formatter are you using?

Comment: Are you using the format code option?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064480/how-do-you-change-the-formatting-options-in-visual-studio-code.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled Python "IntelliSense" which seems to have done the job

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are probably using a code formatter like prettier.

you can either disable or change the way it formats by looking at what formatter you have.

Comment: The OP could be using other code formatters.