# VS Code - Prettier is formatting differently for me than others

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier is behaving differently for me compared to my team mates.

We all have same version `9.5.0` of prettier installed on our VS Code.
We all have same configuration of prettier.

Still it is formatting my typescript file differently for one particular line than others and because of this the deployment is failing when I push anything from my machine and works for everybody else.

Does anybody face this?

Which part should I check to see the difference?

**Update 1**

One thing we found that is different is the VS Code version.

I have version 1.67.2 installed my colleague has 1.63.2 installed.

Could this be the reason?

**Update 2**

This is the exact line where I am getting prettier error on my machine for wrong formatting while this same formatting is considered correct by prettier for other machines

[image]

And this is how prettier formats the line on my machine (then devops complaint that it is a wrong formatting)

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue and even we updated VS code to the latest version in both side, the formatting is still different. We're using same prettier version and have same configuration too. have you got any solution?

Comment: @rener172846 - Not yet, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same isssue.
in my case I run

`npx prettier --version`
on both computer and each one return different prettier version.
so although the prettier extension in vscode was 9.5.0 for both pcs. the npm module installed for the project in `node_modules` was different.

I installed the same prettier module for both computer and the restart vscode and problem solved

Answer (score 10):

I think there is a bug with the prettier extension. Although I had my default formatter set to the prettier extension in the settings UI, I had to re do it manually.

Open any file, right click in the editor screen, click `Format document with` and choose `Prettier - Code formatter`.

The local prettier config and the one vscode uses should work now

Comment: Strange though, it works as you say, but as soon I save the file prettier goes crazy...

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed multiple formatters and you aren't using the correct one. Try to specify it manually in command palette. Check out this [answer (Solution A)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246538/12444149)

Comment: No, I do have the prettier selected as the default formatter

Comment: Maybe share the problematic line? You can also try to run prettier in console and see if it still behaves different.

Comment: Updated the question with the problematic line.

Comment: Looks like you have set different line length then the others, check in your formatter settings, [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html).

Comment: This is the first thing I checked. All the settings of prettier and lint are same for all the machines. I even tried the `eli chen` answer but that too did not work

Comment: Did you tried to run Prettier from console, does it produce the same output as vscode? [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html)