# Visual Studio 2022 place curly braces in the same line in javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2022

How can i force Visual Studio to maintain curly braces in the same line when auto format is done?

Example:
I write this code:

```
$('#details-modal').on('change', '#Foo1', function (e) {
    var bar = $('#Foo2 option:selected').text();
})
```

When i add ; the code gets formatted like this:

```
$('#details-modal').on('change', 
    '#Foo1', 
    function (e) {
        var bar = $('#Foo2 option:selected').text();
    });
```

How can i avoid this behaviour and maintain the first code style?

Thank you

Comment: Probably you'll have to use another formatter For this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064480/how-do-you-change-the-formatting-options-in-visual-studio-code/58246538#58246538

Answer (score 0):

I post this in case anyone has the same problem.

In my case, it was not visual studio 2022 the tool which was causing the line breaks, it was Resharper.

I have disabled the wrapping options in Javascript inside Resharper and now it is working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in Visual Studio 2022.  I'm not using Resharper so the previous solution didn't work for me.  What did work was going to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Tabs, and changing the Indenting option from Smart to Block.

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]